# Accessing a multidimensional array using a one dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

If I have the following initialized... (fyi, in the code I'm basing it off of, both variables are dynamically created)

```
// Start of Code that MUST stay unchanged.
var myPrimaryArray = [["Potato","Walrus"],42,[["Your father was a hamster", "Target"],362]];
var locationArray = [2][0][1];
// End of Code that MUST stay unchanged

//What to put here to get "Target"?
```

How do I make this return "Target", with only those two variables? (Not knowing the depth into either array I have to go ahead of time.)

Comment: i have updated my answer , check it out!

Comment: I appreciate the updated answer, but you're still changing one of the initial vars, sorry if I'm unclear, ... the point is those are the initial vars I have to start out with. Both those vars will be dynamically generated, which is why I can't change them. As such, this assumes I don't actually know what the value in location array will actually be, or the actual layout of myPrimaryArray. All I know is that location array holds the position of where in myPrimaryArray "Target" is. If I could do something like "MyNewVar = myPrimaryArray[locationArray] that'd be great, but I don't think it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution (altered text for stackoverflow, hope it still works for anyone seeking a solution similar to mine.) It's cumbersome, but it should work.

```
// Start of Code that MUST stay unchanged.
var myPrimaryArray = [["Potato","Walrus"],42,[["Your father was a hamster", "Target"],362]];
var locationArray = [2][0][1];
// End of Code that MUST stay unchanged


getArrayObjectWithLocationArray(myPrimaryArray,locationArray)



function getArrayObjectWithLocationArray(myArray, myLocationArray){
var myArray = stringToPositionArray(myString);
if (myLocationArray.length > 1}{
    return getPanelWithPositionString([myArray[myLocationArray[0]], myLocationArray.splice(0,1))
} else {
    return myArray[stringToPositionArray[0]];
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hopes this will return  `target`

```
var myPrimaryArray = [["Potato","Walrus"],42,[["Your father was a hamster", "Target"],362]];
var locationArray = myPrimaryArray[2][0][1];
alert(locationArray);
```

**output:**

```
Target
```

To be fun , check your Code:

> locationArray = **myPrimaryArray** [2][0][1];

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but the code I'm providing is what I have to work with (it's an example of something I can't really change). The point is that I have to get "Target" from myPrimaryArray using locationArray as its provided. Changing the locationArray isn't an option for me.

Comment: @RobG ha ha !, Sorry  , for my bad english!

Comment: That's cool, my English is pretty rubbish at times too, and it's my first language!